# PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have simple-ish PHP website. On each page of the site I start by including a link to my database connection script:

This script just contains the connection to the database:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

// =====MYSQL SETTINGS ===== //
$db['db_host'] = "127.0.0.1";
$db['db_user'] = "mysqlusername"; 
$db['db_pass'] = "mysqlpassword";
$db['db_name'] = "databasename";
// =====END OF MYSQL SETTINGS ===== //

foreach($db as $key => $value){ 
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}
$dbconn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);    
if(!$dbconn){        
    die("Database connection failed");
} 
?>
```

Back on the main web page I then include links to other files/scripts that contain elements of the page - i.e. a link to a script that shows the menu/navigation,  a link to a banner slideshow, etc. - on a busy page there might be 15 or so of these include files. A typical include looks like this (this one gets and displays some reviews from the database):

```
<?php
//show reviews
$mainreviewstate = "Y"; //testEnabled Y or N
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, Company, Desc FROM tblreviews WHERE Enabled = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconn);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $mainreviewstate);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $Id, $Name, $Company, $Desc);
    confirmQuery($stmt);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
*'the reviews would show here'*
} //end if stmt while loop

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} //end if stmt query is not empty
?>
```

..so each of the includes uses the $dbconn connection made in the first include file to connect to the database and then runs the prepared statement and closes the statement at the end - "mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);"

My site is hosted on shared hosting and I was looking through the server log and there were quite a few entries for "PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections" and referencing the $dbconn mysqli_connect in the connection include file.

So my question is, should I be closing the connection and when should I close it? - As mentioned one page may include 10 to 15 include files each of which runs a statement and fetches data from the database. Do I need to close the connection after each "include" (after each prepared statement) or do I need to add another include to the bottom of the web page to close the connection to the database once the page has finished loading - i.e.

1. include to connect to the database
2. includes to prepared statements to fetch and display data from the database
3. more includes....
4. include to close the connection to the database

As mentioned I'm on shared hosting so I can't increase or amend the number of connections possible in MySQL.

Should I be closing my connection and if so, when and where?

Many thanks for reading.

I thought the lines:

```
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

would affectively close the the connection but I realise now they just close the statement.

Comment: What does the documentation say about this?

Comment: The error "Too many connections" usually happens when you use persistent connections or when your script opens more than 1 connection at a time.

Comment: Unrelated, but I wonder why you are using mysqli at all. Why not use PDO? The way you are using mysqli is quite convoluted. Perhaps using PDO would be better for you as it is the de facto standard extension to connect to databases.